# How to copy exif comments to XMP description

Tags: exif, exiftool

In my favourite photo viewing software, FastStone Image Viewer, the only way to add description to the photos is the exif comment field. However, when uploading images to filckr, the title or description fields are not affected by my existing exif comments of the images. I found that if the description is provided in the XMP format, flickr indeed registers and uses them.

I have tried other photo management or viewing software, which supports XMP metadata, but I have not been satisfied with any of them. Therefore, It seems to me, that the best way of keeping my comments when I upload the pictures to flickr is to somehow mirror the exif comments to the XMP description tag. Is there any software which would allow me to do this easily?

As an alternative, the command line tool [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) should be able to do this, but as a first time user, I find it hard to make it do what I want it to do. Could someone perhaps give me a hint on how to use the ExifTool to copy the exif comments to XMP description?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used FastStone Image Viewer before, but I installed it to try and help.  From what I can tell, the only metadata that it can edit is the Jpg Comment field, which technically isn't in the Exif data block.  If that's the field you're filling then the command you would want to use would be something like

```
ExifTool "-Description<Comment" <file/dir>
```

If that doesn't work, check out [ExifTool FAQ #3c](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q3) to try and figure out what the exact field you want to copy would be.